# Why is the li taller than the a child tags

Tags: html, css

I don't know why the li tags are 1px taller than the a tags the code is as following
the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Wy8z/

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
background-color: #5A9AFF;
}

#nav > #nav_container > ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav > #nav_container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#nav > #nav_container > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1b1b1b;
}

#nav > #nav_container > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}


<div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this leads the a tags to be 38px and the li 39px and i am unsure why this is?

Comment: mind creating a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `a` elements are `inline` by default. That's why you've had to add padding to the `li` element; the `li` is taking the height of its content, which is `inline` (it doesn't count the padding). The problem with this approach is that `li` elements also have some inherent padding, and it's not equal to the padding you're giving the `a` element.

Setting the `a` tag to `display:block;` and removing the padding from the `li` will solve this issue by displaying the `a` element in `block` rather than `inline`, and causing the `li` to only take the size of the `a` element (and not more) minus any forced padding that you were trying to add in compensation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATG9q/)

```
#nav > #nav_container > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav > #nav_container > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: No. li has no inherent padding. You can easily check this in firebug, etc. In any case, if it did have padding, changing the a element from inline to block would not remove the padding. The 1px difference is the height of the text (the ascender height = 16px + the descender = 3px = 19px) versus the line-height (1.25 times the Em height = 20px)

Comment: @CarlMarkham thanks for the explanation! one thing that annoys me in CSS is when we have to set some "magical", seemingly unrelated property to make it work. Understanding how the property is related feels really nice :)